# How do I add images to an Xamarin iOS project and make them available in Interface Builder?

Tags: xamarin.ios, interface-builder, xamarin-studio

I am working in Xamarin to build an iOS iPad app.

I have created a folder called Resources in the project root e.g. ProjectName/Resources. Within here is a subfolder ProjectName/Resources/Images. I have added 2 images into the Images folder.

Then, in Interface Builder (in Xcode), I have added a UIImageView to my xib file and gone to the Image drop down in the attributes inspector. There are no images available to select.

Maybe I have to add them via Xcode instead? If so what are the correct steps and file structures to use?

**What is the correct way to work with images and make them available for selection in Interface Builder?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xamarin Studio only exports images that would live in the top-level app bundle directory when the app gets compiled. This is because Xcode's .xib files only seem to be able to refer to images in the top-level app bundle.

There are multiple ways of achieving your goal:

The first option is to specify a `LogicalName` to be whatever you want the name to be inside of the compiled app bundle. In Xamarin Studio, this property is called the `Resource ID` (may or may not be available depending on which version of Xamarin Studio you are using - it was only recently added). You can also set the LogicalName by editing the *.csproj file like so:

```
<BundleResource Include="Icons\icon.png">
  <LogicalName>icon.png</LogicalName>
</BundleResource>
```

Normally, that `Icons\icon.png` file would be copied into the iOS app bundle as `Icons/icon.png`, however, the LogicalName property overrides the relative install path/name. In this case it would be copied over as simply `icon.png`.

As another example, you can also do this:

```
<BundleResource Include="Icons\iOS\icon.png">
  <LogicalName>AppIcon.png</LogicalName>
</BundleResource>
```

This will copy the `Icons\iOS\icon.png` file into the root of the iOS app bundle and also rename it to `AppIcon.png`.

A second option is to simply move your image file(s) into the `Resources` folder. The Resources folder is a special directory that gets stripped out of the default path names when copied over to the iOS app bundle. In other words, `Resources\icon.png` would be copied over into the root of the iOS app bundle as `icon.png` rather than `Resources\icon.png` as is the case with normal project directories.

A third option is to simply register other "Resource" directories of your own (and they can exist within other directories, including the default Resources directory).

For example, you could have the structure in your project:

```
Resources/
   Icons/
      icon.png
      icon@2x.png
```

And in your *.csproj file, edit the following tag:

```
<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
```

and replace it with:

```
<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources;Resources\Icons</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
```

This will ensure that the icon.png and icon@2x.png files are installed in the root of the iOS app bundle.

Comment: At the moment I am using your second option.
The third option sounds better to me though.What if I wanted multiple sub directories within "Resource" ? e.g.
Resources/
  Icons/
    icon.png
    icon@2x.png AND Resources/
  Content/
    feature.png
    feature@2x.png. Would I add the following to the .csproj file? <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources;Resources/Icons;Resources/Content</IPhoneResourcePrefix>

Comment: Yes. You can have any number of Resource directories.

Comment: If you accept my answer, that would probably help other users with similar questions find this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The only way to do it is to open the *.csproj file in a text editor right now

Comment: Option 2 works well, but Option 3 is imo a far better solution. sadly Option 3 is not working for me. Despite Cleaning and restarting both xamarin and xcode. Using Xamarin 4.2.2

Comment: Sorry about that... it's been fixed in git master and will be in 4.2.3